# Overloading conversion ctor and conversion operator in `To to = from;` and `To to = {from};`

Tags: c++, constructor, overloading, typecast-operator

### In brief

When I learned about C++ initialization these days, I found `To to = from;` behaves differently from `To to = {from};`, where `from` is of another type `From`:

If conversion constructor `To::To(From &)` and conversion operator `From::operator To()` are provided, both of them will be considered for `To to = from;`, which will cause a compile error. However, only the conversion constructor will be considered for `To to = {from};`, which will work fine. What the hack here?

### To be detailed

Code to reproduce this case on GCC 10.3 with C++20 applied:

```
class From;

class To {
    public:
        To() = default;
        To(From &) {std::cout << "conversion constructor\n";}
};
class From {
    public:
        operator To() {std::cout << "conversion operator\n"; return {};}
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    From from;
    // To to1 = from;
    To to2 = {from};
    return 0;
}
```

Uncomment the line and we'll get the error:

```
case.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
case.cpp:17:14: error: conversion from ‘From’ to ‘To’ is ambiguous
   17 |     To to1 = from;
      |              ^~~~
```

From what I can tell, `To to = from;` is [copy initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization). And [this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator#Explanation) says "the conversion functions and constructors are both considered by overload resolution in copy-initialization", which is pretty much about the error.

What about `To to = {from};` then? It is listed as an old way of [copy initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization). But it's up untill C++11 and is probably not the case. Is it [list initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization)? Can someone give an explanation of how it deals with conversion constructor and conversion operator?

### Additional discussion

I also experimented with [C++11 in-class initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization), with a few more lines of code:

```
class InClsInitialization {
    private:
        From from;
        // To to1 = from;
        To to2 = {from};
};
```

The result seems to be the same (i.e., uncomment the line and we'll get the same error), though I don't find which category of initialization it belongs to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`To to = from;` is copy-initialization. It falls under [[dcl.init.general]/16.6.3](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.general#16.6.3), according to which

> ... user-defined conversions that can convert from the source type to the destination type or (when a conversion function is used) to a derived class thereof are enumerated ... and the best one is chosen through overload resolution ([over.match]). ...

Both converting constructors of `To` and conversion functions of `From` are considered. (Since this is copy-initialization, `explicit` functions will be ignored.)

`To to = {from};` is copy-list-initialization. Copy-list-initialization is a type of copy-initialization, but has different rules. Since `To` is not an aggregate, it falls under [[dcl.init.list]/3.7](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list#3.7), according to which

> ... constructors are considered. The applicable constructors are enumerated and the best one is chosen through overload resolution ([over.match], [over.match.list]). ...

Thus, conversion functions are not considered. (Explicit constructors are considered, but the program is ill-formed if one of them is chosen by overload resolution.)

Comment: For code in the "Addition Discussion" section, are they also considered copy initialization and copy list initialization, respectively?

Comment: @Lusssac yes, the initialization syntax has the same meaning there.

Comment: I was trying to figure that out on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization). Unfortunately it's not mentioned what would take place inside a class. Thank you for your answer!